# Spark cached Dataset not reused in join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

After some complex transformations I call cache on dataset.

```
val complexDs = (some joins and transformations).cache
complexDs.count //invoke action and store dataset in memory
```

Then I define method like this:

```
def getCountForType(input: Dataset[Row], tp: String):Dataset[Row] = {
input
.groupBy($"column1",$"column2")
.agg(sum(when($"typeColumn" === tp,1).otherwise(0).as("some_column_name"))    }
```

Now I create several new datasets by executing this method.

```
val newDs1 = getCountForType(complexDs, "aType")
val newDs2 = getCountForType(complexDs, "bType")
```

And funny part comes. When I call action on each of this several new datasets separately, I get results instantaneously and on SparkUI you can tell there is in memory table scan...But when I try to do join like this:

```
val finalDs = newDs1.as("a").join(newDs2.as("b"), $"a.column1" === 
$"b.column1" && $"a.column2" === $"b.column2)

display(finalDs)
```

I can tell something is wrong as execution gets terribly slow and on SparkUI, one dataset is read from cache and other one generated from beginning. Anyone has idea what is going on?

### UPDATE

When i try(just for testing purposes) to union newDs1 and newDs2, I see there are 2 in memory table scans and results are instantaneous. Here are 2 screenshots of DAG. Union - reads already calculated data from memory, Join - calculates one dataset from beggining.

[image][image]

Comment: volumes of DSs?

Comment: Testing data was small, for instance complexDs is just 80mb in memory. Nevertheless i do not see how could that affect this strange behaviour?

Comment: Version of spark is?

Comment: @thebluephantom Spark version 2.2.1. Also tried with 2.3.0 and same behaviour

Comment: Bugs exist in SPARK as well

Comment: can you put in the complete spec and code and I will then run on and look on databricks

Comment: @thebluephantom here is a code where you try and see this behavior...  https://pastebin.com/9xi5wAGB thank you for your help!

Comment: OK, as I am most curious myself. To me it sounds like a bug. But I am going to try this out.

Comment: Will look tomorrow. I looked at a similar style Q and got reuse in some cases.

Comment: Did you resolve this?